# Same Script works in cmd command ,but faied in GhostScript.net

Tags: ghostscript, ghostscript.net

my Environment is.

- Windows10 64bit
- VS2015 ,GhostScript9.27,
- is C# programming language

And I'm using GhostScript.net to invoke GhostScript

here is my code.

```
string inputFile = "D:\\112.pdf";
string outputFile = "D:\\output.pdf";
GhostscriptProcessor ghostscript = new GhostscriptProcessor();

 List<string> switches = new List<string>();

 switches.Add("-o");
 switches.Add(outputFile);

 switches.Add("-dNoOutputFonts");

 switches.Add("-sDEVICE=pdfwrite");

 switches.Add(inputFile);

 ghostscript.Process(switches.ToArray());
```

and I try the script by the windows CMD Window

```
gswin64.exe -o D:\output.pdf -dNoOutputFonts -sDEVICE=pdfwrite D:\112.pdf
```

it works,

but when I run it in C# by GhostScript.net, it always gives error.

> An error occured when call to 'gsapi_init_with_args' is made: -100

Do anybody know? thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: THis isn't really a Ghostscritp question, since Ghostscript itself works. Error code -100 is gs_error_Fatal, which essentially means 'something truly bad happened'. My immediate thought would be that you haven't specified a switch[0], I dn't know if Ghostscript.NET will do that for you. Try putting switches.Add("-dNothing"); as the **first** switch and then add the others.

Comment: @Kens ,thanks your advise, it works when add "-dNothing" and  there  is another way  is  add "gs" . but  meet another problem  is  if the fileName Contains  chinese characters  ,  not  work